# TomEE DataSource isn't found

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, ejb, apache-tomee

I have a strange problem regarding TomEE and using a DataSource specified in tomee.xml.
It might be worth noting that I'm using Netbeans, TomEE and MySQL. Running on Ubuntu 13.04 (Xubuntu latest)

The tomee.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
    <Resource id="booktablesDS" type="DataSource">
        JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/book_tables
        UserName juser
        Password jpassword
        JtaManaged true
    </Resource>
</tomee>
```

And a small codesnippet, testing the connection pool:

```
@Resource DataSource booktablesDS;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

    Connection c = booktablesDS.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM BOOKS");
```

The output I'm getting from TomEE is:

```
SEVERE: null
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

Full stacktrace follows.

```
May 06, 2013 11:08:53 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EJBTest]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
May 06, 2013 11:08:54 AM MainS processRequest
SEVERE: null
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at MainS.processRequest(MainS.java:35)
    at MainS.doGet(MainS.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:524)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:493)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 22 more

May 06, 2013 11:08:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/EJBTest]
```

Basicly it feels like netbeans is deploying the project with another tomee.xml file? Disregarding the values in my tomee.xml, which is under tom-ee/conf/tomee.xml

Help would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your url is wrong.

```
jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/book_tables
```

should be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book_tables
```

Can you double-check whether the MySQL driver JAR is really there in `tomee/lib` folder.

Comment: That was the problem. The // wasn't in there... Oh well, good to know! Now I'm having some nasty persistance issues instead...

Comment: Glad it works now. It is often the problem when "//" is in the wrong place. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your code like this:

```
@Resource(name = "booktablesDS", type = javax.sql.DataSource.class)
DataSource booktablesDS;
```

Comment: Nope, still the same error output:
SEVERE: null
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Comment: Have you added jdbc dependency into your pom.xml(I suppose you use maven)?

Comment: Well NetBeans builds it automatically but it's using maving as default. However, no I haven't added the jdbc dep, since i thought it wasn't necessary because the server has it in the _BASE_/lib folder. I haven't touch a pom.xml file yet

Comment: I found very similar issue related to eclipse. Take a look at [Fix Eclipse Server](http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/configuring-a-mysql-data-source-in-tomee/) section. I mean, seems when you run AS it can't find your datasource because it uses defaults. As an option, try to deploy your application from command line(not from IDE) and check is the output the same.

Comment: Yes I saw that option as well, however NetBeans has no config files for the servers. It actually uses the installpath of the server. I remembered when i setup a nice connection pool in Tomcat, with the context.xml file under _BASE_/conf, that fully worked when i ran it through NetBeans. But I can't for the love of god get TomEE to work properly! Not through NetBeans at least.

Comment: Bingo.. I really wish there wasn't an OpenEJB class also called "DataSource"